# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'LabelModule')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-module

The error happens when I import my LabelModule into the FormFieldModule. Then I use the Label Component in the FormField Component.

I do not import/use those modules/components anywhere else.

This is my FormFieldModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { FormFieldComponent } from './form-field.component';
import { LabelModule } from '@app/shared';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [FormFieldComponent],
    imports: [CommonModule, LabelModule],
    exports: [FormFieldComponent],
})
export class FormFieldModule {}
```

This is my LabelModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LabelComponent } from './label.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [LabelComponent],
    exports: [LabelComponent],
    imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class LabelModule {}
```

The thing is when I import the modules like this, it works.

```
import { LabelModule } from '@app/shared/components/form-elements/label';
import { ValidationErrorModule } from '@app/shared/components/form-elements/validation-error';
```

The import shortening works everywhere else. But not here.
Another thing I noticed - it works flawlessly when I build the project for production and serve it, no errors, no warnings, it just works. Seems to only be the development issue.

Comment: Rebooting your IDE helps sometimes..

Comment: I get that error in the browser, every time I start the project, even if I use the terminal

Comment: Hmm.. so maybe that module is not exported correctly from the shared barrel file (index.ts)?

Comment: I feel like it must be exported correctly since like I mentioned, it works just fine when I build the project for production and serve it.